# How to combine SFDX Development lifecycle with integration sandbox refresh?

Tags: salesforcedx

We are using SFDX in a CI/CD process with good results, however we need sometimes to refresh our integration sandbox. When the Connected App we used to authorize SFDX cli and store the public key used for private-key authentication is copied over from production, the Connected App Consumer Key is changed, and we need to update the secrets in our CI/CD to work around this problem.

Are there better strategies to work with SFDX and integration sandboxes?

Comment: Duplicate of  [How to access a refreshed Sandbox in CI/CD?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/341386/how-to-access-a-refreshed-sandbox-in-ci-cd)