# How to access a refreshed Sandbox in CI/CD?

Tags: sandbox, cicd

We are using the classical machine-to-machine approach to connect to our DevHub to create scratch org, but in pre-release we need to connect to sandbox environments, which we would like to refresh nightly.

Although the key associated to the connect app we use to sign the jwt is  not changed during sandbox refresh, the consumer id is changed every time we refresh the sandbox

How can we get access to the sandbox after we have refreshed it, in CI/CD? If we have access to production, is there a way we can use it to get login access to sandbox?

Comment: By _cryptographic key_ are you referring to JWT flow? That flow does not use a consumer secret. Please edit your question and include client code embedded in your CI/CD process that shows a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you are correct, the client ID changes, I updated my question

Comment: Second answer by @xn in the link referenced above has the right idea. You'll have to flesh it out.